# pass bundle between activities

Tags: android

I try to pass a bundle between two activities. This bundle contains a Serializable object. 
this is my code

```
       XmlReader myReader = new XmlReader(is);

       Intent myIntent = new Intent(view.getContext(), MyRegister.class);
       Bundle b = new Bundle(); 
       b.putSerializable("xmlReader",(Serializable) myReader);
       myIntent.putExtras(b); 
       startActivity(myIntent);
```

but new activity is not executed. When I remove  b.putSerializable("xmlReader",(Serializable) myReader); it works

Help me to olve this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not convinced that XmlReader is serializable - you may want to double check that. If it does not implement the `Serializable` interface, just casting it to it will not help.

Also I think if you need the XML in multiple activities, you may pass that document around or the raw XML as string.

If you only need it in the target activity, call the XmlReader there.